# java smallest integer in an array recursive method

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I need to write a recursive method which looks through an array and finds the smallest index, however I am having a bizarre issue, for some reason my given test array seems to return a result of 10. I have tried debugging in eclipse and something very odd happens, my findMinAux method does indeed find -10 to be the smallest value and when I press the "step into" button it does seem as if it is about to return -10 but then it goes into some weird loop and startIndex starts increasing for some reason. If anyone has any advice as to where I am going wrong it would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Here is my code:

```
public class Q1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] testArr = {12,32,45,435,-1,345,0,564,-10,234,25};
    findMin(testArr);

}

public static int findMin(int[] arr) {

    int result = findMinAux(arr,arr.length-1,arr.length-1);
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;

}

public static int findMinAux(int[] arr, int startIndex, int smallest) {

    if(arr[startIndex]<smallest) {

        smallest = arr[startIndex];

    }

    startIndex--;

    if(startIndex>=0) {

        findMinAux(arr,startIndex,smallest);

    }

    return smallest;

}

}
```

Comment: Hint: I am not allowed loops, this is a university assignment where I have to use recursion as stated in my post :) @CannedMoose

Comment: the third argument to findMinAux(arr,arr.length-1,arr.length-1) is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

First, you should initiate `smallest` with the last element if you want to search from the end of array:

```
 int result = findMinAux(arr,arr.length-1,arr[arr.length - 1]);
```

Secondly, you should reassign `smallest`:

```
if(startIndex>=0) {
    smallest = findMinAux(arr,startIndex,smallest);
}
```

Comment: ah yes, its always a silly error isnt it *facepalm* this solved it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
    class Minimum {
    int minelem;
    int minindex;
    Minimum() {
        minelem = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        minindex = -1;
    }
}

public class Q1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] testArr = {12,32,45,435,-1,345,0,564,-10,234,25};
    findMin(testArr);
}
public static int findMin(int[] arr) {
    Minimum m = new Minimum();
    m = findMinAux(arr,arr.length-1,m);
    System.out.println(m.minindex);
    return m.minindex;

}

public static Minimum findMinAux(int[] arr, int lastindex, Minimum m) {

    if(lastindex < 0) {
        return m;
    }

    if(m.minelem > arr[lastindex]) {
        m.minelem = arr[lastindex];
        m.minindex = lastindex;
    }

    return findMinAux(arr,lastindex - 1, m);

}
}
```

I have used another class here for simplification. Please check if this solved your problem meanwhile I am explaining why and how it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this implementation works fine

```
 public static int findMinAux(int[] arr, int startIndex, int smallest) {
        if(startIndex < 0)
            return smallest;
        if(arr[startIndex] < smallest){
            smallest = arr[startIndex];
        }
        return findMinAux(arr, startIndex - 1, smallest);
}
```

And also you has a typo in calling this funtion, the last parameter must be an value from array, in your case the last value, not the last index.

```
        int result = findMinAux(arr,arr.length-1, arr.length - 1);
```

change to

```
        int result = findMinAux(arr,arr.length-2, arr[arr.length - 1]);
```

Comment: why does it need to be this way? I have used user6690200 solution and my code now works

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to say that in this way it works fine. Anyway, a general rule of recursion is: 

1. The base case.
You must always have some base cases, which can be solved without recursion.

2. The recursion.
For cases that are to be solved recursively, the recursive call must always be a case that makes progress toward a base case.
To avoid unexpected errors it is preferred to check for `1` and after this to do `2`

Answer (score 0):

This approach works with a single method and an overloaded version so you don't have to pass the initial values

```
    public static int findMin(int[] arr) {
    int index = 0;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      min = Math.min(arr[index], min);
      return findMin(arr,index+1,min);
    }


   private static int findMin(int[] arr, int index, int min) {
    if(index < arr.length)
    {
         min = Math.min(arr[index], min);
         return findMin(arr,index+1,min);
    }
    System.out.println(min);
    return min;
   }
```

The second method is private so from outside the class, only the first/default method can be called.

Comment: yes but using an extra auxiliary method means you can provide a method needing only one argument which we are encouraged to do for good practice

Comment: I've revised the answer uncase you prefer it this way. Just another option.

Answer (score -2):

See this code. In every iteration, elements are compared with current element and index in increased on the basis of comparison. This is tail recursive as well. So it can be used in large arrays as well.

```
public class Q1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] testArr = {12, 32, 45, 435, -1, 345, 0, 564, -10, 234, 25};
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(find(testArr, 0, testArr.length - 1, testArr[0]));
    }

    public static int find(int[] arr, int currPos, int lastPos, int elem) {
        if (currPos == lastPos) {
            return elem;
        } else {
            if (elem < arr[currPos]) {
                return find(arr, currPos + 1, lastPos, elem);
            } else {
                return find(arr, currPos + 1, lastPos, arr[currPos]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns the smallest element

Comment: Maybe it is expected to not to change its signature.

Comment: Point of using recursion is not just calling a function. Code should be concise and easily readable